# Kill a process, wait a random amount time then start the process again?

Tags: python, bash, unix, raspberry-pi

I have recently starting programming in python and am still at a very beginner level all round with programming. I have created my own command line python script that I am running on my Raspberry PI. This script works fine but I need to reset it every now and then.

I was wondering if there was a way to create a .sh script that will do the following loop:

1. Start the python script
2. Wait a random amount of time between 60 minutes and 100 minutes  (Echo the amount of time the script will run for)
3. Then kill the process and wait between 5 minutes and 15 minutes - Cool down (Echo how long it will be in cool down for)
4. Then loop back to the top

I know there might be an extremely simple solution to this but hey I'm still learning! 
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your system has the `timeout` command, it's really easy:

```
while true; do
    t="$(shuf -i 60-100 -n 1)"
    echo "run for $t minutes"
    timeout "$t"m python yourScript
    t="$(shuf -i 5-15 -n 1)"
    echo "pause for $t minutes"
    sleep "$t"m
done
```

If you don't have the `timeout` command, replace the line `timeout ...` with

```
python yourScript &
sleep "$t"m
kill %+
```

Comment: Hi Socowi, I've noticed that upon starting the script it gives no errors however does not kill the process or continue on the loop. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

MINUTESTOSLEPP=$1
MINUTESTOSLEPP=$MINUTESTOSLEPP"m"



function sleep_and_run_rasberry_pi()
{
    echo $MINUTESTOSLEPP
    python rasberry_pi.py
    sleep $MINUTESTOSLEPP
    echo "The Script has been halted for "$MINUTESTOSLEPP" minutes"

    kill -9 `ps -ef | grep rasberry_pi | awk '{print $2}' | head -n1`

    sleep 10m
}

################# MAIN Function #####################
while 1
do
  sleep_and_run_rasberry_pi
done
```

Run the script with the following command 
**sh testscript.sh 45**

Meaning it will sleep for 45 minutes and kill the raspberry_pi process

Comment: [SC2009 Consider using pgrep instead of grepping ps output.](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2009)

Comment: So for this example I am building the script on my MacBook then putting it on the Pi. `MINUTESTOSLEPP=$1
MINUTESTOSLEPP=$MINUTESTOSLEPP"m"


sleep_and_run_example()
{
    echo $MINUTESTOSLEPP
    python example.py
    sleep $MINUTESTOSLEPP
    echo "The Script has been halted for "$MINUTESTOSLEPP" minutes"

    kill -9 `ps -ef | grep example | awk '{print $2}' | head -n1`

    sleep 10m
}

################# MAIN Function #####################
while 1
do
  sleep_and_run_example
done
`

Comment: @VinodKumar You can use `pid=$!` after `python` to get the PID more easily. @Daimen Try to remove the `function` keyword.